# US Border With EU Wife

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, uk-citizens, borders, spouses

Hopefully a quick question - I am a US citizen currently residing in the UK on a visa.  I am traveling to the US with my wife, who is a British citizen.  We do not yet share a last name (due to just not filing the paperwork yet and just being married recently).

I've read online that since we are a family we should join the same line together when coming into the US border at the airport.  However, because we don't share a last name, would this still apply? Should we just use our own appropriate lines?  Would there be any issues with using our own lines?

Comment: What type of Visa is she travelling on?

Answer (score 4):

You should join the same line. Some things, [like the $10,000 cash reporting requirement](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/195/~/currency-and-monetary-instruments---amount-that-can-be-brought-into-or-leave), apply to the family/group as a whole so they'll want to see you together. The family names don't matter: some people don't change their name when they marry and some countries/cultures have no tradition of doing that, but they are still a family.

Comment: It's worth noting that people residing apart aren't supposed to share a customs declaration form even if they're related (although a passport inspector once discarded the separate form my girlfriend handed him even though we didn't reside in the same country, so this is obviously not a strict requirement).  At https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/441/~/travelers-eligible-to-file-a-joint-or-family-declaration-on-a-cbp-form-6059b one may read that the definition of "family" explicitly includes people in an unofficial relationship, so it surely includes spouses with different names.